# Eclipse recent files

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any list of recently opened files in eclipse?

If yes then is there also any shortcut for it?

Frequently I close classes in editor because there are too many of them opened. But in a few minutes I need them again. Maybe you solve this problem differently?

Thanks!

Comment: I laughed so much. I make the same all the time :)

Answer (score 54):

- Probably your best option is to use "Quick Switch Editor" (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>**) but it displays the opened files only. There you have quick list along with filtering by starting to type first chars of file name. To make it useful, you may increase the size of opened files/windows before closing - *Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Number of opened editors before closing*. After you reach this threshold the oldest file open is closed in order to make room for newly open one.
- The list of the files recently opened is displayed in `File` menu, just before the `Exit` menu option.
  There you'll find the already open and last closed files. 
  If you want to use it extensively then you should probably increase the size of the items - *Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Size of recently opened files list*. You can quickly invoke one of last 9 filed with **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,[Digit]**.
- A drawback of third option "Open Resource" (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**) is that the default list looks sorted, so it is not based on the most recent date of use. Also "Open Type" (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>**) has a long listing over time and you should enter part of the name to get a shorter match.

My initial comment is based on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler and is applicable to current latest Eclipse (4.5 Mars) too.

Comment: I wonder how useful the numbered shortcut could possibly be... how often does one think "I need to open the 7th file I had open" without having the list in front of them, at which point you may as well move your cursor to it and click.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, you should not remember which is _the 7th file open_. Moreover this number changes when you open another new file. 
What you should do is use **Alt+F**, then see what is the number before desired file and then type it (if it is below 10).
  I also do not think that this is the most elegant way but this is the current situation. For the other options you should also check some list but then you may narrow it by typing part of the name.

Answer (score 23):

If you click on the File menu, you would see the list of recently used files. By default there are four of them. To increase the no, goto Window-> Preferences-> General -> Editors. You can set to as many as 15

Comment: You can't set it to as many as you want. I tried setting it to 20 and got an error message saying I could only have up to 15. I've edited your answer.

Answer (score 17):

If you know the class name you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (for classes) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> fo any other resource file. You don't have to type full name just the uppercase letters. Eclipse shows recently opened file in topmost section and other files in the lower section.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to goto last edit location.

For a complete list of shortcuts goto Help>KeyAssist. Also checkout Tips and Tricks under the same menu.

Comment: +1 for Ctrl+Shift+R. I would never find anything without that shortcut.

Comment: yes you don't have to type the whole world to find files. You can also use wildcards * to even speed things up

Answer (score 14):

I'm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Unfortunately it is not possible to use "regular expressions" as for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, but I think this is what are you looking for.

Comment: IMO this should go to the top

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the "last edit location" shortcuts on the toolbar (the yellow arrows, alt+left) if you wish to reopen a recently edited file, or use the short list of recently opened under the "File" menu (right above "exit")

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin called "RecentEditors" that shows a list of recently closed files, sorted by close time (so the last closed editor is at the top). There is also a command (and keyboard shortcut) to directly re-open the last closed editor.

You find the plugin on the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/recent-editors), and [GitHub](https://github.com/achimmihca/RecentEditors).